# Replacing large dataset Multiple Conditions Loop with faster alternative in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, for-loop

I'm trying to perform a nested loop onto a Dataframe but I'm encountering serious speed issues. Essentially, I have a list of unique values through which I want to loop through, all of which will need to be iterated on four different columns. The code is shown below:

```
def get_avg_val(temp_df, col):
    temp_df = temp_df.replace(0, np.NaN)
    avg_val = temp_df[col].mean()

    return (0 if math.isnan(avg_val) else avg_val)

Final_df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list, columns=col_names)

""" Inserts extra column to identify Securities by Group type - then identifies list of unique values"""
Final_df["Group_SecCode"] = Final_df['Group'].map(str)+ "_" + Final_df['ISIN'].map(str)
unique_list = Final_df.Group_SecCode.unique().tolist()

""" The below allows for replacing missing values with averages """
col_list = ['Option Adjusted Spread','Effective Duration','Spread Duration','Effective Convexity']

for unique_val in unique_list:
    temp_df = Final_df[Final_df['Group_SecCode'] == unique_val]    

    for col in col_list:
        amended_val = get_avg_val (temp_df, col)

        """ The below identifies columns where Unique code is and there is an NaN - via mask; afterwards np.where replaces the value in the cell with the amended value"""
        mask = (Final_df['Group_SecCode'] == unique_val) & (Final_df[col].isnull())
        Final_df[col] = np.where(mask, amended_val, Final_df[col])
```

The 'Mask' section specifies when two conditions are fulfilled in the dataframe and the np.where replaces the values in the cells identified with Amendend Value (which is itself a Function performing an average value).

Now this would normally work but with over 400k rows and a dozen of columns, speed is really slow. Is there any recommended way to improve on the two 'For..'? As I believe these are the reason for which the code takes some time.

Thanks all!

Comment: kindly share a sample of ur data, with expected output. Easier to work with, do benchmarks on, and allow a large sample of SO to respond

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if this is what you are looking for, but if your goal is to impute missing values of a series corresponding to the average value of that series in a particular group you can do this as follow:

```py
for col in col_list:
    Final_df[col] = Final_df.groupby('Group_SecCode')[col].transform(lambda x: 
                                                            x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Comment: Thanks for the shout. To make sure I understand, would those Nan values I am trying to filter for, be filled by the mean of the filtered series or the mean of the whole column?

Comment: It would be filled by the aggregated values grouped by “Group_Segcode”. Did I misunderstand you there?

Comment: Yeah so essentially by filtering out with the following code:                                     
mask = (Final_df['Group_SecCode'] == unique_val) & (Final_df[col].isnull())                 I am placing two filters on the dataframe: 1. The Unique value; and 2. the Nan values corresponding to that Unique Value

Comment: Could you please try the above snippet on your dataset and let me know if it produces the desired results?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE - Found an alternative way to Perform the amendments via Dictionary, with the task now taking 1.5 min rather than 35 min.

Code below. The different approach here allows for filtering the DataFrame into smaller ones, on which a series of operations are carried out. The new data is then stored into a Dictionary this time, with a loop adding more data onto it. Finally the dictionary is transferred back to the initial DataFrame, replacing it entirely with the updated dataset.

```
""" Creates Dataframe compatible with Factset Upload and using rows previously stored in rows_list"""
col_names = ['Group','Date','ISIN','Name','Currency','Price','Proxy Duration','Option Adjusted Spread','Effective Duration','Spread Duration','Effective Convexity']
Final_df = pd.DataFrame(rows_list, columns=col_names)

""" Inserts extra column to identify Securities by Group type - then identifies list of unique values"""
Final_df["Group_SecCode"] = Final_df['Group'].map(str)+ "_" + Final_df['ISIN'].map(str)
unique_list = Final_df.Group_SecCode.unique().tolist()

""" The below allows for replacing missing values with averages """
col_list = ['Option Adjusted Spread','Effective Duration','Spread Duration','Effective Convexity']

""" Sets up Dictionary where to store Unique Values Dataframes"""
final_dict = {}

for unique_val in unique_list:
    condition = Final_df['Group_SecCode'].isin([unique_val])
    temp_df = Final_df[condition].replace(0, np.NaN)

    for col in col_list:
        """ Perform Amendments at Filtered Dataframe - by column """
        """ 1. Replace NaN values with Median for the Datapoints encountered """
        #amended_val = get_avg_val (temp_df, col) #Function previously used to compute average
        #mask = (Final_df['Group_SecCode'] == unique_val) & (Final_df[col].isnull())
        #Final_df[col] = np.where(mask, amended_val, Final_df[col])
        amended_val = 0 if math.isnan(temp_df[col].median()) else temp_df[col].median()
        mask = temp_df[col].isnull()
        temp_df[col] = np.where(mask, amended_val, temp_df[col])

        """ 2. Perform Validation Checks via Function defined on line 36 """
        temp_df = val_checks (temp_df,col)

    """ Updates Dictionary with updated data at Unique Value level """
    final_dict.update(temp_df.to_dict('index')) #Updates Dictionary with Unique value Dataframe

""" Replaces entirety of Final Dataframe including amended data """
Final_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(final_dict, orient='index', columns=col_names)
```